# MarkLogic : how to copy databases?

Tags: marklogic

I search for best process to copy databases in same MarkLogic server.
My objective is to have same data between two databases (production and pre-production for instance).
I need an on demand copy.

Today, I identify 2 solutions:

- use [mlcp copy](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/copy): I found this approach too slow
- use [backup/restore](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore) operations by modifying directory structure backup before restoring into 2nd database.

What is the best? Is there another?

Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: Please clarify- you are using one server with a pre-production and production database or are you using two servers, one is pre-production and one is production? You mention two environments, but also mention "same host."

Comment: Also, have you tried increasing the batch size and tweaking other configurations to speed-up the mlcp process?

Comment: Hmm, good point. If you are talking about a single host, or even a single cluster, you could potentially do forest replication. One quick question though if it is wise to have production and pre-production data in one cluster. Pre-production stress-tests would hurt production performance for instance..

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I make changes into my initial post to clarify what I'm search for. I need a on demand copy operation between two database. For now, databases are on same server. MarkLogic says us to use mlcp for copy. But, modify backup directory structure to restore into the 2nd database is faster. I'll try to adjust mlcp configuration to improve it

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a reasonable use case for either:

- Database Replication, or
- Flexible Replication

You'd have to register the pre-production cluster as a foreign cluster to the production cluster (a standalone host is also seen as a cluster). You can then use either of the two.

Database replication is much more straight-forward to configure. Flexible replication allows for redacting/filtering your data along the way.

Initial catch up won't be particularly fast, but once caught up, pre-production is going to be kept in synch with only a small (configurable) lag.

HTH!